# Bash Shell Script Inner loop of Nested Loops not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In attempting to rename a set of files with variations of (1-26), Left/Right and png/bmp I have the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

NUMBER_LIST=$(seq -f "%03g" 1 26)
EXT_LIST=("png" "bmp")
SIDE_LIST=("right" "left")
for NUMBER in $NUMBER_LIST
do
    for SIDE in $SIDE_LIST
    do
        for EXT in $EXT_LIST
        do  
            OLD="${SIDE}_${NUMBER}.${EXT}"
            NEW="${NUMBER}_${SIDE}.${EXT}"
            mv $OLD $NEW

        done
    done
done
```

Only files that are designated **right** and **bmp** get renamed. So
it looks like it is only iterating through the outermost loop, and not iterating through the inner loops (just uses first element).

I've looked elsewhere on the net but am having trouble finding anything relevant.

Any guesses as to what might be wrong?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: You're creating _arrays_ (except for `$NUMBER_LIST`), so you must base your loops on arrays, e.g., `for SIDE in "${SIDE_LIST[@]}"`. Additionally, I suggest not using all-uppercase variable names.  Referencing an array variable as if it were a scalar - e.g., `$SIDE_LIST` - implicitly returns the array element with index `0`, so you're looping over 1 value only.

Comment: I agreed with @mklement0 on all accounts, should resolve your issue.

Comment: @mklement0 That works. I'm not sure I understand how the case defines it as a scalar. Could you elaborate? Does the array declaration (ie $SIDE_LIST) need to be lowercase? The element declaration (ie  for SIDE) need to be lowercase? Or the element reference (ie $SIDE)?

Comment: It's just best practice to reserve upper case variables for the shell, lower case for users.

Comment: @WoodMath: The case issue is unrelated, as implied by miken32's comment. It's _how you reference_ an array variable that determines whether a scalar is returned: `$SIDE_LIST` is a scalar reference, whereas `"${SIDE_LIST[@]}"` returns the entire array.

Answer (score 4):

Your first assignment

```
NUMBER_LIST=$(seq -f "%03g" 1 26)
```

assigns the string created from the output of `seq` to `NUMBER_LIST`. Your next two assignments

```
EXT_LIST=("png" "bmp")
SIDE_LIST=("right" "left")
```

create arrays. With an array variable, `$EXT_LIST` is equivalent to `${EXT_LIST[0]}`, that is, it's just the first element of the array. To iterate over all the values of an array, use

```
for EXT in "${EXT_LIST[@]}"
```

---

Note that your outermost loop works because you are iterating over the whitespace-separated strings stored in `NUMBER_LIST`. That is, if `NUMBER_LIST` is `0 1 2 3`, then `NUMBER` is set in order to 0, 1, 2, then 3. The same would apply to your faulty attempt at a loop. Consider

```
EXT_LIST=("png bmp" "gif tif")
for EXT in $EXT_LIST; do
```

`EXT_LIST` would expand to `png bmp`, and since the expansion is not quoted, `EXT` would be assigned `png`, then `bmp`. If you incorrectly wrote

```
for EXT in ${EXT_LIST[@]}; do
```

then `EXT` would take `png`, `bmp`, `gif`, then `tif` as its values. The equally incorrect

```
for EXT in "$EXT_LIST"; do
```

would produce a single iteration, with `EXT` assigned the value `png bmp gif tif`.

Answer (score 0):

Even better, because simpler and because arrays are not needed here, is changing the vars' values and leaving the dereferences as-is:

```
EXT_LIST="png bmp"
SIDE_LIST="right left"
```

Comment: That works in this case, but is generally not advisable, because the words in the variable values are subject to pathname expansion (globbing) when used in a `for` loop. Using arrays is the robust choice.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, avoiding the loops, is starting with filenames that are correct.
Writing regex for 001 .. 026 is also possible, but i only check digits in the first find and check the number later.

```
regex_side="\(left\|right\)"
regex_ext="\(bmp\|png\)"
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype sed -regex ".*/${regex_side}_[0-9]\{3\}\.${regex_ext}" | while read -r f; do
   filename="${f##*/}"
   side_number="${filename%.*}"
   side="${side_number%_*}"
   number="${side_number##*_}"
   if [ ${number} -lt 26 ] && [ ${number} -gt 0 ]; then
      printf "%s\n" "mv ${f} ${f%/*}/${number}_${side}.${f##*.}"
      # When you like the mv statement, delete the # on the next line
      # mv "${f}" "${f%/*}/${number}_${side}.${f##*.}"
   fi
done
```

EDIT: Added solution with `sed`.

You can avoid find with a sed solution. This will be slower, since bash will need to call sed for every file. I think the sed solution is easier to understand:

```
regex_side="\(left\|right\)"
regex_ext="\(bmp\|png\)"
for file in *; do
   # When your shell supports it: newname=$(sed -e "..." <<< "${file}")
   newname=$(echo "${file}" |
             sed -e "s/^${regex_side}_\([0-9]\{3\}\)\.${regex_ext}$/\2_\1.\3/")
   if [ "${file}" != "${newname}" ]; then
      number="${newname%%_*}"
      if [ ${number} -lt 26 ] && [ ${number} -gt 0 ]; then
         printf "%s\n" "mv ${file} ${newname}"
         # When you like the mv statement, delete the # on the next line
         # mv "${file}" "${newname}"
      fi
   fi
done
```